# How to show options in telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to write a bot telegram.How to put possible option in my bot.I insert a picture of sample bot with this functionality.
[image]

Answer (score 124, accepted):

For that, you have to talk to BotFather.

1. In the Telegram App, open the chat with BotFather.
2. Send him `/setcommands`. He will present you with a list of your bots.
3. Pick the bot for which you want to set the command menu.
4. Compose and send the command list. Using your image as an example, these 4 lines should do:

start - Description 1
menu - Description 2
help - Description 3
stop - Description 4

Note that command part of each line(left side of `-` signs) must have just **lowercase** characters, and **no slashes**. There should also be **spaces** around the `-` sign.

Once you complete this process, **exit and kill** the Telegram App. Re-open it, go to the chat with your target bot, type a `/` (or tab on the `/` button next to the text field), the command menu should come up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, i think there is no way to control admin and user commands. if you don't want users to see your admin commands you should not put them here.

Comment: EDIT ROLLBACK: ***Note that each command should be written in lowercase, and that the command may not begin with a /slash. There should also be spaces around the - sign. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: No need to restart Telegram, works instantly

Answer (score 8):

**New dynamic way to set commands**

Telegram introduced a separate method [`setMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands) which allows you to set commands via API directly from your code.

```json
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "command": "start",
      "description": "Start using bot"
    },
    {
      "command": "help",
      "description": "Display help"
    },
    {
      "command": "menu",
      "description": "Display menu"
    }
  ],
  "language_code": "en"
}
```

Moreover, it allows you to customize commands per language code with `language_code` parameter

Answer (score 2):

Without json.dumps([]) I get error response from Tlg: {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': "Bad Request: can't parse commands JSON object"}

The code below works as expected.

```
{
  "commands": json.dumps([
    {
      "command": "start",
      "description": "Start using bot"
    },
    {
      "command": "help",
      "description": "Display help"
    },
    {
      "command": "menu",
      "description": "Display menu"
    }
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$comandos = [
["command" => "a", "description" => "aaa"],
["command" => "b", "description" => "bbb"],
["command" => "c", "description" => "ccc"],
];

defineMenuOptions($comandos);

function defineMenuOptions($comandos) {

$comandosEnc = "setMyCommands?commands=" . json_encode($comandos);
$retorno = file_get_contents(API_URL.$comandosEnc);

}
?>
```