# How can i do slash command list instead keyboard buttons in telegram bot using c#?

Tags: c#, button, keyboard, telegram-bot

I have some problems with command views in telegram bot. i'm using telegram.bot SDK with c# asp.net:

```
var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new [] // first row
                {
                    new KeyboardButton("/help"),
                    new KeyboardButton("/start")
                },
                new []
                {
                    new KeyboardButton("/news"),
                    new KeyboardButton("/lots")
                }
            }, resizeKeyboard: true);
```

The result is a similar keyboard buttons, but i need a list of commands. like this:
[Want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNigU.png)
But i cant find how to do it and have this: [Have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlHbw.jpg)

Comment: You have to add the command list manually with BotFather. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458436 "this answer") for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set commands from [BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather),

Or you can use `SetMyCommandsAsync()` and `GetMyCommandsAsync()` methods to edit your commands programmatically.

Comment: Hi Muaath , Any idea how to use SetMyCommandsAsync and GetMyCommandsAsync? It seem not work..

Comment: I didn't use them. But they should work, Now some Tg clients has some errors with personalized commands.

Comment: @Eyalk: The command must be lower case. The description can be anything. If command is not lowercase, you get 400:BAD_REQUEST