# How to call the Telegram Bot API `setMyCommands` using curl?

Tags: curl, telegram-bot

I'm trying to call the `setMyCommands` API via `curl` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041696/7296427). I first tried

```sh
curl -L -X "POST" \
    "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TELEGRAM_TOKEN"'/setMyCommands?commands=[{ "command": "command", "description": "description" }]'
```

`curl` printed the following error.

```
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position
```

Then I tried to use `curl` with `--globoff` flag.

```sh
curl --globoff -L -X "POST" \
    "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TELEGRAM_TOKEN"'/setMyCommands?commands=[{ "command": "command", "description": "description" }]'
```

Now it printed the following error.

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

What is the correct way to call it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Windows. Try this:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"commands\":[{\"command\":\"test\",\"description\":\"description with spaces\"}]}" https://api.telegram.org/bot$TELEGRAM_TOKEN/setMyCommands
```

The trick is to escape double quotes in the JSON with a backslash. It would work even for the command you are using, sending the commands in the query, but using `-d` (shortcut for `--data`) option makes it easier to include spaces in the description of the commands.